# Why didn't Java use existing class language specification grammars for generic type specifications?

Tags: java, generics

I've learning more about Java Generics this week. I learned of bounded types when specifying a generic. The description is something along the lines of:

```
class <T extends A & B & C> ...
```

Meaning T must of a type that extends A and implements B and C. Therefore, in the generic definition, instances of type T may access any methods of A, B or C.

T may extend only one class, and it must be the first in the list. All extends may be interfaces as well.

This notation can be confusing. It's not obvious that A is a class. If you make mistake and B were the class, the compiler won't let you continue, but it doesn't give an compile time error message that's particularly obvious. It doesn't state, "Class B must be the first in the list."

I was thinking that Java already has a way of defining classes and interfaces. Why not leverage that existing syntax for Generics as well. So instead of:

```
class <T extends A & B & C>
```

why not:

```
class <T extends A implements B, C>
```

Comment: "Why" you'd have to ask the language designers.  I suspect it's mostly personal preference.  I can see that the slightly different syntax makes it more distinct and easier to read.  But I'd be just guessing at the reason.

Comment: Short answer to *"why not: `class <T extends A implements B, C>`"* Because `C` is then a second generic type argument, not a second bound on `T`.

Comment: @Andreas well we could assume the syntax is `<T extends A implements B & C>` for the sake of discussion.

Comment: @Kayaman And that is different syntax, so back to that question, and .... oh yeah, we just explained why syntax had to be different, didn't we? Which I also did in a [long answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48361470/5221149).

Comment: @Andreas yes, but you just edited the part I was talking about in there afterwards.

Answer (score 6):

You're confusing the `extends` keyword in a generic type argument with the `extends` keyword in a class declaration, and the `extends` keyword in an interface declaration.

The keyword doesn't mean the same thing in those contexts.

When a `class` declaration says `class A extends B implements C, D`, then `B` must of type `class`, while `C` and `D` must be of type `interface`.

When an `interface` declaration says `interface A extends B, C`, then `B` and `C` must be of type `interface`.

When a generic type declaration says `<A extends B & C & D>`, then `B` can be a `class` **or** an `interface`, while `C` and `D` must be of type `interface`.

As you can see, the `extends` keyword doesn't in and of itself specify whether the types must be of type `class` or `interface`. The context in which the keyword is used defines that.

---

Now, as for your question of why they didn't keep existing syntax.

They couldn't, because if you changed `<A extends B & C & D>` into `<A extends B, C, D>`, then `C` and `D` is ambiguous as to whether they are two independent arguments, or whether they are additional bounds to `A`.

The problem is that an argument list already use commas (`,`) to separate the arguments, and when declaring multiple base types the syntax already use commas (`,`) to separate them, so when you combine the two, you end up with ambiguous syntax.

They had to change one of them, so they chose to stick with comma as the argument separator, and then use `&` to separate multiple base types.

---

And why not use `<A extends B implements C & D>`? Why should they? `extends` can already be used to reference both classes and interfaces, so letting it do that here is not "new".

Also remember that `A` itself can be a `class` or an `interface`. Since it's common syntax for classes and interfaces, they chose simple common syntax for `<TYPE extends TYPE & TYPE & TYPE>`, where `TYPE` is `class` or `interface`.

Answer (score 0):

There must be some confusion here. Extends is no different from implements. By not requiring implements Java allows the user to pass either classes or interfaces into generics. If you think about things from a design perspective

```
class <T extends A & B & C>
```

and

```
class <T extends A implements B, C>
```

do the same thing but `class <T extends A implements B, C>` would require you to create a new class if you wanted to pass an interface as the first type. Using `extends` instead of `implements` creates an interchangeable relationship between interfaces and classes which allows for better code design.

Comment: What do you mean "require to create a new class"? `class Foo<T extends A implements B, C>` would be one class, and the only thing the user of that class can affect is what `T` is (with the given constraints). The constraints are already given, and no matter which syntax is used is irrelevant.

Comment: Since you're talking about "pass an interface as the **first** type", you might be confusing `A`, `B` and `C` with generic types. However they're supposed to represent a class and 2 interfaces respectively. They won't be passed in, they're written in stone. There's only one generic type `T`.

Comment: I'm not sure what language the original poster refers to for other languages that implement that standard of syntax for generics, but if the key word `extends` is used for requiring a class that extends another class and the key word `implements` is reserved for interface implementation than the constraints could only be  class, interface, interface instead of the possibility of interface, interface, interface. 

Basically I was referencing the flexibility of what the constraints could be set as and not the flexibility of what T could be.

Comment: It seems you drew some wrong conclusions. Once you write the class, it's set whether it's `class, interface, interface` or `interface, interface, interface`. Neither of the syntaxes gives more flexibility. `A, B, C` is chosen by the writer of the class, `T` is chosen by the user of the class.

Comment: I think you are misreading my answer. In terms of designing a programming language that allows class design to be extended through several iterations of work you would want `class D<T>` to not be rewritten if `T` was `T extends A implements B, C` vs `T implements A, B, C`. 

If the writer needed to change the beginning type from a class to an interface, there would be a change of the class signature because T would need a rewrite from `T extends A implements B, C` to T implements A, B, C`. This changes the use of T.  T could not be a class because of the change.

Comment: That would mean the writer would need to do extra refactoring inside of the class because places that might have relied on T being a class (a concrete class in my example) would no longer be type safe. I personally would just create a new class at that point to avoid modification of that class. If I needed a type with different implements but it did not extend a class what's the point of modifying my specific class? Java eliminates this situation by forcing a flexible syntax that allows refactoring to be limited when class A is changed to interface A and vice a versa.

Comment: If you're going to change an existing class, you're in danger of breaking things. There's absolutely no advantages that either of the syntaxes provides in this case. Your suggestion that the current syntax makes it somehow easier to refactor just isn't true. No matter what syntax we're using, if we decide to change the generic signature, we have to fix every place that relies on `T`. At that point it doesn't matter what **syntax** `Foo<T ...>` uses. There's no **extra** refactoring. I'm out for the night.